# Scrapy export csv without specifying in cmd

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I understand how to export my scraped data in to a csv format via

```
scrapy crawl <spider_name> -o filename.csv
```

However I'd like to run my spider from a script and automatically write to csv (so I can use schedule to run the spider at particular times). How could I implement this into my code and where would it go? I.E would it go into pipeline or my actual spider assuming this can be done.

Comment: what do you mean by 'from a script'? another python script? a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy uses pipelines to post process the data you have scraped. You can create
a file called `pipelines.py` which contains the following code which exports
your data into a folder `exports`. Here's some code that I use in one of my
pip projects

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter, JsonItemExporter

class ExportData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}
        self.exporter = None

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file_to_save = self.files.pop(spider)
        file_to_save.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

class ExportJSON(ExportData):
    """
    Exporting to export/json/spider-name.json file
    """
    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file_to_save = open('exports/%s.json' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file_to_save
        self.exporter = JsonItemExporter(file_to_save)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

class ExportCSV(ExportData):
    """
    Exporting to export/csv/spider-name.csv file
    """
    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file_to_save = open('exports/%s.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file_to_save
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file_to_save)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()
```

You can view the project code on [github](https://github.com/kirankoduru/arachne/blob/master/arachne/pipelines.py). You just need to add these class names in your scrapy settings correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set scrapy's **FEED_URI** setting in settings.py to the file you want to save the data.

```
FEED_URI = '*filename*.csv'
```

You can also set the custom setting in your spider file,

```
custom_settings = {
     'FEED_URI': filename_{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%b-%d")}.csv',
     'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
     'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 }
```